# No "nvcc" in "cuda-10.2/bin" toolkit patch

Tags: cuda

I have a working cuda-10.0 toolkit and 470 driver. I need to use new virtual memory management features that I found in 10.2 driver. And I can't install more than 10.x because my old video card has compute capability 3.0.

So after applying new toolkit with:

```
sudo sh ./cuda_10.2.1_linux.run --toolkit --silent --override
```

it is as I think successfully installed:
[image]

But now in folder with "cuda-10.2" there is almost nothing, "bin" folder only has uninstaller and no "nvcc" and others. And newly created link links to that "nothing". How to deal with it?

I tried official docs and googling but nothing was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [patch updates](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.2-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=CentOS&target_version=7&target_type=runfilelocal) for CUDA 10.2 do not contain complete toolkits. The idea behind a "patch" is that it contains only the files necessary to address the items that the patch is focused on.

To get a full CUDA 10.2 CUDA tookit install, you must first install using a full CUDA 10.2 toolkit installer, and a typical filename for that would be `cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run` (runfile installer to match your indicated runfile installer usage).  After that, if you decide you need/want the items addressed by the patch, you must ***also*** install the desired patch.

Note the statement on the [download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.2-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=CentOS&target_version=7&target_type=runfilelocal):

> These patches require the base installer to be installed first.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Could you please help me to understand the cause of that tricky bug? I want to understand for futture how the CUDA memory works. I have posted detailed explanation of the code in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75468890/cudamalloc-executed-many-times-leads-to-memory-corruption